# How to POST an object that contains a nested object without creating the nested object and without using an IRI?

Tags: php, post, doctrine-orm, nested, api-platform.com

I'm trying to create a Customer object that contains a nested Gender object.

When I create a Customer I want to pass an existing Gender. 
 --> The problem is that Api Plateform is trying to create the nested Gender that I give to it.

I would like not to use the IRIs but the nested object entirely.

So I created my "Customer" entity with normalization and denormalization groups.

Customer Entity :

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *      normalizationContext={"groups"={"customer.read"}},
 *      denormalizationContext={"groups"={"customer.create"}}
 * )
 * @ORM\Table(name="customers")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CustomerRepository")
 */
class Customer
{
...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Gender", inversedBy="customers", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"customer.read","customer.create"})
     */
    private $gender;
```

The Gender entity :

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *      normalizationContext={"groups"={"gender.read"}},
 *      denormalizationContext={"groups"={"gender.create"}}
 * )
 * @ORM\Table(name="genders")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\GenderRepository")
 */
class Gender
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     * @Groups({"gender.read","customer.read","customer.create"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",unique=true, length=20)
     * @Groups({"gender.read","gender.create","customer.read","customer.create"})
     */
    private $genderName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",unique=true, length=3)
     * @Groups({"gender.read","gender.create","customer.read","customer.create"})
     */
    private $genderCode;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Customer", mappedBy="gender")
     */
    private $customers;
```

Each time I send a POST on /api/customers

with :

```
{
  "lastname": "string",
  "firstname": "string",
  ...
  "gender": {
    "genderName": "Test",
    "genderCode": "T"
  }
}
```

Gender is created each time ..

How can I say to ApiPlateform "Do not create Nested Object but use existing plss" ? 
Any way to handle that ?

Thanks you very much. 
Tony,

Answer (score 0):

you have to add IRI to gender.

```
{
  "lastname": "string",
  "firstname": "string",
  ...
  "gender": "/genders/id"
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer.
I would like to send the entire nested object because my customer model on my Front Angular is like this:

Customer:
id
...
gender: Gender   (Gender is an Object that point on a Gender Model) 
...

I got an error if I set an Iri String instead of a Gender object. And I would to know if there is any way to send the full gender Object to my Api Plateform.


I thought that create a special route and redefine what I get from the front in a controller.

Or stop using the Front templates and simply send an untyped Json object to match with my back model...

Comment: with cascade={"persist"} you can save nested object automatically